# Auto completion of XML File with Rinzo XML Editor in Eclipse with an xsd-shema is not working

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd, eclipse-plugin, xml-editor

I am using **Eclipse Mars** (4.5.0) and the **Rinzo XML Editor** and I am having problems regarding the **auto-completion** that Rinzo offers in regard to an **xsd shema**.

I couldnt make it run in any way and im not sure what is the problem.
I guessed that the editor selects the right xsd shema depending on what is defined with the schemaLocation attribute in the XML document. My xsd file is called device.xsd and is located in the same directory than the XML. I declared it in the following way in the XML:

```
<file xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com device.xsd">
```

I tried many different things to make it run, also with making new basic XML-XSD-Combinations and nothing seemed to be working ... I guess it would already help me if someone could give me a working combination, so I can try it with that and see if the problem is in my files or somewhere in the settings or whereever.

Thank you very much in advantage. And I hope that this post is well formed, since it is my first of its kind.

Greetings, Molloch.

Answer (score 1):

I could make the it run now on another setup with the following tags:

```
<file    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="device.xsd">
```

On the original it is still not running, I assume it is some kind of Problem related to Eclipse running on a virtual machine ...